# Core data and querying results of a query

Tags: ios, core-data, predicate

I have two entities in my model, `A` and `B`. `A` has a to-many relation to `B`, and its inverse is a to-one relation back to `A`. I'd like to fetch results of entity `B` using `A` as follows:

1. Perform a fetch request on entity `A` with some predicate.
2. On the results returned by this request, drill through to all the related `B`s and on these filter by a second predicate.
3. Return all the valid results of entity `B`.

Of course I can do (1) and then filter an array of `B`s using the second predicate. However I know this is suboptimal.

How can I do this most efficiently, even with a single fetch and predicate?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I'm not really sure what you are asking.  It surely would help if you gave more details.

So, I'll just have to guess...  Keep in mind the fetch request can only return one type of entity.  So, if you want the thing that is the many side of the relationship, fetch that.

You can use 'dot' notation in your predicate...  I'd also probably do the search backwards...

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Employee"];
fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"department.name like 'Support'"];
```

There is 1-to-many relationship from Department to Employee.  The above grabs all employees that belong to a department with 'Support' in the name.

Answer (score 1):

If you are already holding an instance of A, just access the related B instances through A's accessor.

If you need to directly fetch all the B's related to a particular A (you don't in this case), you'd build a fetch request for the B entity, with a predicate based on the (inverse) relationship of Bs to A. (The specific syntax will depend on the inverse relationship name, and whether that inverse is a to-one or to-many.)